# why doesn't A=\"\" grep $A behave like grep ""?

Tags: bash, grep, variable-substitution

I am on Linux, using bash.

```
$ A=\"\"
$ grep $A
nomatch
""
""                         <- (returned by grep)
$ grep ""
imatcheverything
imatcheverything           <- (returned by grep)
```

I would have expected `grep $A` to act like `grep ""`. Why does it literally match `""`? I expect this because the shell appears to get in `grep`'s business all the time; For example (to my knowledge), `grep \\\\` is first looked at by the shell, which turns it to `grep \\`. After this check, grep sees the scraps and searches for lines containing `\`.

I suspect it has something to do with the order in which the shell substitutes variables and looks at quotes. If the shell removes quotes before the variable substitution step, it would explain this behavior.

---

On an unrelated note, I am looking for a resource that has relatively complicated regexes (reading them, not writing them. Ideally, they ask something like 'what does this regex do?'), preferably BRE or ERE.

Comment: `A = \"\"` should have given you a command not found error. What shell are you using?

Comment: That was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place: it is not `grep` that is not working as you expect. It is `bash`. `bash` is the tool that deals with quotes. Try `echo $A`

Comment: Capital letters for shell variable names is an anti-pattern: they are reserved names. ( see the manual: it says don't use them, and why ).

Comment: @ilkkachu I expected \"\" to behave similarly compared to "" because something like `A=\[` `grep $A`. A is passed into grep (containing a literal, escaped opening bracket), but triggers a invalid regex error.

Comment: @ChristopherLee, ah, no... `A=\"\"` stores the string `""` in the variable, while `A=\[` stores the string `[`. Outside quotes, the backslash makes pretty much any following character non-special, and gets removed itself. (Inside double-quotes it only escapes the characters that are special there, so `"`, `$`, backslash and backtick.) The `[` by itself is indeed an invalid regex. You'd need either `A=\\\[` or `A="\\["` (or `A="\["`), or `A='\['` to store `\[` so that the regex engine in grep also sees an escaping backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't evaluate quotes after expanding parameters. The expanded value is only processed for [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) if variable isn't quoted but quotes are no longer reinterpreted. They become part of the "words" just like any other non-IFS and non-glob values. In your example, Bash passes the `""` argument to grep as is because they aren't word split and they aren't glob patterns.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ A = \"\"
$ grep $A
```

In Bash, assignment is without whitespace around the equals sign, none in front, none behind.

```
$ A=\"\"
$ grep $A
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep ""` calls grep with one argument that is an empty string.

`grep $A` (i.e.`grep \"\"`) calls grep with one argument which is literally two double quotes.

If you want to know what the shell sends to the command, you can use a small script to find out like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

args = sys.argv[1:] #skip the first one which is the name of the cmd

print(f"Number of args: {len(args)}")

for index, arg in enumerate(args, start=1):
    print(f"Arg {index}: Length: {len(arg)}")
    for char in arg:
        print(f"{ord(char)} {char}")
```

Example 1:

```
❯ ./showargs.py ""
Number of args: 1
Arg 1: Length: 0
```

Example 2:

```
❯ A=\"\"
❯ ./showargs.py $A  
Number of args: 1
Arg 1: Length: 2
34 "
34 "
```

Example 3:

```
❯ ./showargs.py foo \\\\
Number of args: 2
Arg 1: Length: 3
102 f
111 o
111 o
Arg 2: Length: 2
92 \
92 \
```